# Group returned records by date in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android app that returns a `ListView` of football fixtures from a Firebase database. The list works at present but I'd like to improve the UI. The image below shows what I have and what I'd like to achieve;

[image]

On the lefthand side I have a layout xml that loops through the records and displays the date per record, but what I want to do is return a list that displays fixtures under 1 date if they are the same and if not then display under the new date (as on the righthand side).

Below is the layout of my xml;

[image]

To give you an idea of the code (please ask if you'd like to see the code, I got marked down over posting 50 lines recently);

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="dateofmatch" />
```

The date red header is inside the listview xml.

I'm guessing this is a recursive function that works out all of the children of a date and then draws out the list.

My question is, which approach would you recommend as I don't want to kill performance and I'm torn between 2-3 ways I could do this.

EDIT: Adapter for the ListView

```
public class matchList extends ArrayAdapter<matches> {
  private Activity context;
  private List<matches> matchList;

  public matchList(Activity context, List<matches> matcheslist) {
    super(context, R.layout.match_layout, matcheslist);
    this.context = context;
    this.matchList = matcheslist;
  }

 @NonNull
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.match_layout, null, true);
    TextView textViewDate = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    TextView textGameID = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtGameID);
    TextView textViewTime = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
    TextView textViewHomeTeam = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtAction);
    TextView textViewAwayTeam = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtAwayTeam);
    TextView textViewPitchNo = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtPitch);
    ImageView imgLiveIco = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imgLive);

    matches match = matchList.get(position);
    textViewDate.setText(match.getDate());
    textGameID.setText(match.getGameID());
    textViewHomeTeam.setText(match.getHomeTeam());
    textViewAwayTeam.setText(match.getAwayTeam());
    textViewTime.setText(match.getTime());
    String fdate = helper.dateFormater(match.getDate() , "EE dd MMM yyyy" , "dd/MM/yyyy");
    textViewDate.setText(fdate);
    textViewPitchNo.setText("Pitch " + match.getPitch().toString());

    if(match.getPlayed() == 1) {
        imgLiveIco.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        imgLiveIco.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    return listViewItem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code where you are setting the data from the database to the ListView/RecyclerView.

Comment: @AlexMamo just updated the question with the adapter code

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, I recommend you use a simple if statement. What I don't understand from your code is the fact that the `dateofmatch` is apart of the entire item view or not. If it is apart of that view, then you need to find that view using `findViewById()` method and use the if statement like this:

```
if (dateOfPreviousMatch.equals(dateOfMath)) {
    //set visibility of dateofmatch to GONE
} else {
    //set visibility of dateofmatch to VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: dateofmatch is part o f the layout that defines the entire list, though I do see a direction where the code above is going, I'll play around with that idea